# Can i deploy an asp.net MVC 3 web application in a production server or in a hosting domain using free software?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7, iis-express

I am learning asp.net MVC 3 by my own since 6 months and i am enjoying it; i have downloaded MS visual web developer 2010 express for free which comes also with free database . i have the following 2 questions
1. but my question is if i can build a web site that runs on a production server using these free softwares offered by Microsoft
2. and can i also deploy the production web site using IIS 7 express which is also free ?
BR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will be able to deploy the web site you have developed using the free tools to any production web server running IIS.
However, IIS Express is not intended for production use, but rather for development. Refer to [Scott Gu's post on IIS Express](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/06/28/introducing-iis-express.aspx)
You might be interested in free asp.net hosting. Look at [aspspider.net](http://www.aspspider.com/)
If you need more robust and professional hosting for your site, go with a paid hosting service. I use [discountasp.net/](http://www.discountasp.net/) a lot, but there are plenty of others.

Comment: thanks for ur reply,, so does this mean that if i use a hosting company such as discountasp.net then i do not need to have IIS or even a database as these will be provided by the hosting company?

Comment: IIS will be provided. You can use sql compact without additional charges, but if you want SQL Server you will typically need to pay additionally. That is how it works at discountasp.net, but you should shop around, find something that fits your needs